# How concerned should I be about herbicides in compost horse manure?

Tags: vegetables, herbicide, manure

I just filled most of my raised beds with locally sourced composted horse manure. When I was looking for straw mulch I started reading a bunch of horror stories about aminopyralid contamination in hay and that it's risky to use hay/straw/horse manure because of how damaging this long lasting herbicide is for broad leaf veggies like beans squash peas etc. Now I'm feeling paranoid and started a sprouting test with the manure vs potting soil. I feel like even if the test passes, I'm going to worry about partial contamination. How worried should I be? I'm in Florida if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

The Health and Safety Executive  in the UK concluded that crops grown on land affected by contaminated manure are  'safe to eat', assuming the plants actually grow in the first place. Whether you actually want to eat  them or not is another matter, but that information is contained here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=477, along with full information regarding this problem. That  link contains two embedded links which might be of interest, though obviously. it is mostly aimed at  the UK market. I don't know  whether hormone weedkillers (aminopyralid in particular) were  ever withdrawn temporarily or otherwise  where you live, so it's hard to say how safe or not your manure might be.

If it turns out the manure is contaminated after you've done your sowing test, then follow the instructions in the link to deal with it.